# How do I visit a url in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Im working on a small project which I need to send a couple of parameters to another server which has a web service for sending of SMS messages. I'm constructing the URL by calling a method on my controller like so,

```
...
send_sms(number,message)
   sms_url = "http://sms-machine.xx.xx/sendsms/" + number + "/" + message
   #go to the url above
end
```

The resulting page will be a delivery message from the server with either a "NO" or "YES" to show if the message was sent. It is important for the users to know if the sms message was sent or not. So my question is how do I visit the sms url. Is there such a go_to_url function in rails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ruby's [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/classes/Net/HTTP.html) or the much simpler [open-uri](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/open-uri/rdoc/index.html) functionality, eg:

```
require 'open-uri'

status = open("http://sms-machine.xx.xx/sendsms/#{number}/#{message}").read
```

Net:HTTP is loaded by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard `net/http` library to make your own HTTP requests: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/index.html